# How can I fix my bibliography with LaTeX?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Hello I am newbie with Latex and I couldn't compile my bibliography.tex when I comment it the pfd work well but when I uncomment it. the PDF doesn't appear and I couldn't resolve it I tried a lot 
this is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,latin1,utf8]{StyleRapport}
\include{formatAndDefs}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%\makeindex
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{cite}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{slashbox,booktabs,amsmath}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}[1]{\chapter*{#1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
\markboth{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\slshape\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\bsc{\chaptername~\thechapter{} :} #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection{} \ #1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\lhead[]{\small{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\small{\leftmark}]{}
\cfoot[\small{\thepage}]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\include{PageDeGarde}
\dominitoc
\pagenumbering{roman}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Remerciements}
\mainmatter
\include{IntroductionGenerale}
%\mainmatter
\include{Chapter1}
\bibliographystyle{StyleRapport}
\bibliography{Bibliographie}
\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

My bibtex file called bibliography.tex and there is no bibliography.aux or bibliography.bll

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. This is tedious, but is also a good way to find where the error comes from... and maybe to solve it by yourself!

Comment: Well, do you \cite{} a reference somewhere in your code ? Do you compile with bibtex ? Please, as @ebo told you, give a clear and reproducible code. Here we miss a lot of code that you include, and we have tons of code that is probably not related to your problem.

Comment: yes i used \cite{} in chapter1.tex and i use bibtex

Comment: As a side note, you have duplicate declarations of `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}`

Comment: @MakBad What is the exact error message you get? Is it related to no `bibliography.aux` or `bibliography.bbl` files present?

Comment: @Samuel when I compiled my code it works but the bibliography doesn't appear I just had [?] in my PDF. I couldn't find the file Bibliography. aux or bibliography.bbl So i changed the name of bibliography to the same name of my main file which is Rapport.tex

Comment: @MakBad, That means you need to run BibTeX over your file.
When you compile with TeX, you need to compile once, compile your bibliography and then compile another couple of times. Are you using a TeX IDE such as TeXStudio? (F8 compiles BibTeX in TeXStudio)

Comment: Is your file called `bibliography.tex` or `bibliography.bib`? The latter works. The former, I think, does not.

Comment: I am using Textmaker. my biblio file called bibliography.bib. I compile it with PDFLatex+Bibtex+PDFLatex+PDFLatex+SeePDF but I have [?] in my text

Comment: @MakBad so you should try `\bibliography{bibliography}` (with lowercase *b* and *y* instead of *ie*). The command is used as following: `\bibliography{<name-of-your-.bib-file>}`

Comment: @ebo what's the diff it's just a file name no? the problem is that's I can't find my bibliography.aux and in the pdf I had [?] and a white paper

Comment: @MakBad In your document, you call the command `\bibliography{Bibliographie}`, so `natbib` (that uses `biblatex` processing) will look for the file `Bibliographie.bib`. If you don't have this file (but rather `bibliography.bib` as you explained), your references will never be found! Btw, as your example is far from minimal, I think (but not sure)  you don't load `\usepackage{natbib}` that defines the `\cite` command and enables the processing of you `.bib` file...

Comment: If your `.tex` file is called `file.tex`, then you will get a file called `file.aux` when you run pdfLaTeX. And it has to be the *correct* filename. If your `.bib` file is called `Bibliographie.bib`, then you should have `\bibliography{Bibliographie}` in the `.tex` file.

Comment: @ebo `biblatex`? And you don't need `natbib` to use `\cite`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. of course, I meant `BibTeX` (for one's interrest: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/64454)). I didn't knew you could use `\cite` without `natbib`. Is it the case for `\bibliography` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you have several errors in your code.

First, we do not know where your used class `StyleRapport` comes from.  Therefore I just changed it to standard class `article` and commented the class options not useable with class `article`.

Second, we do not have your used bibliography style `StyleRapport`, so I changed it in the following MWE to `plain`.

Now please have a look to the following lines:

```
\documentclass[%
  a4paper,12pt,
% oneside,latin1,utf8 % choose latin1 or utf8!
]{article} % StyleRapport

%\include{formatAndDefs} % ========= no, never \include her, only \input !!
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % == You can't use latin1 and utf8 together!
```

You can only use file encoding `latin1` **or** `utf8`, but not both together!  So please for your class choose one of them, I activated `latin1` for the MWE.

Your line `\include{formatAndDefs}` is simply wrong there, in the preamble you can only use `\input{formatAndDefs.tex}`.  Please see that in an MWE that `\input` is not helpful, because we do not have the file `formatAndDefs.tex` (you saw `\input` with extension `.tex`?).

Then you called several packages double or more. Please do only call packages you know, be careful with the order you call them, and please read the documentations. Then for example you can learn that `\usepackage{colortbl}`is the same as `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. I left the last one commented in the MWE.

Then I reduced the definition for the page header to a minimum and added with package `filecontents` (only for the MWE to have TeX code and Bib file together in one compilable MWE!) an example bib file because you gave us no file.

Now please copy the following MWE to your computer and compile it three times.  It should compile with no errors. Then please study my code and change one step by one step your own code.  Compile after each step (one changing) to see errors at once!

Changed MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Goossens,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and 
               Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[%
  a4paper,12pt,
% oneside,latin1,utf8 % choose latin1 or utf8!
]{article} % StyleRapport

%\include{formatAndDefs} % ========= no, never \include her, only \input !!
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % == You can't use latin1 and utf8 together!

\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{cite}

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % == use only this, delete other color calls!

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead[]{\small{\rightmark}}
\rhead[\small{\leftmark}]{}
\cfoot[\small{\thepage}]{\thepage}


\begin{document}

\include{Chapter1}
text \cite{adams} text 
\nocite{*}  % =============== To have all bib entrys in the bibliography ...
\bibliographystyle{plain} % =========== StyleRapport
\bibliography{\jobname} % ========== uses file created with filecontents!
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image]

If possible, can you provide a link to your used class?